# Show element if another element is outside screen (JS)

Tags: javascript, viewport

If element1 is outside visible area, element2 should be visible. If element1 is inside visible area, element2 should be hidden. (I would like not to use jQuery if possible) This I have so far.

```
function check(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById("element1");
    var div2 = document.getElementById("element2");

    if(div1.top > (window.top + viewport.height )) {
        div2.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div2.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

With this I get the error 'viewport is not defined'. I know it has to be defined but dont really know how to.

Comment: Type “javascript get viewport height” or similar into Google or this site’s own search field, and you will find plenty.

Comment: Yeah, expanding on what @misorude has said, I'm assuming in this instance you're trying to use `visualViewport`? I'm assuming that you've just made a little mistake?

Comment: If you don't care about supporting legacy browsers (like IE), have you considered using [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the function to the scroll event on what element is scrolling and checking that scroll position with the end (as bottom position) of your element1 to check.

This is an example:

```js
function check(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById("element1");
    var div2 = document.getElementById("element2");
  
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > (div1.clientTop + div1.clientHeight )) {
        div2.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        div2.style.display = "none";
    }
}

window.onscroll=check;
```

```css
body{
  height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
 }
 
 #element1{
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

 #element2{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  display: none; /*initial display state*/
  top: 50vh;
  right: 0;
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element2"></div>
```

Also, you can check for the Intersection Observer API which is used sometimes for lazy loading images.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan on supporting really old browsers (like IE11 and below), you can actually use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to achieve what you're doing. The advantage is that the API actually contains configurable logic that can further fine tune at what threshold you want to toggle display state of the target element.

In fact, [almost 74% of global browser traffic actually supports Intersection Observer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver). With the notable exception of Safari. Fret not, [there is a polyfill available if you need it](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill).

Here is an example:

```js
function callback(entries) {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    var elementToToggle = document.getElementById('element2');
    elementToToggle.style.display = entry.isIntersecting ? 'none' : 'block';
  });
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
observer.observe(document.getElementById('element1'));
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
}

.element {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

#element1 {
  background-color: steelblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

#element2 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" id="element1"></div>
<div class="element" id="element2"></div>
```